# Is a linked list better with key or without key?

Tags: c++, input, key

```
class node{
    public:
    int key;
    int data;
    node* next;
    node()
    {
        data = 0;
        key = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
    node(int k, int d)
    {
        data = d;
        key = k;
    }
};
```

I have seen codes where linked list is written without using keys and list is traversed using the index. But if we compare the space and time complexity of both cases which one is better?

Comment: Is a car better or worse with a bucket seat?

Comment: Reusable linked lists don't require `key` fields; that is up to the data structure.  See `std::list`.

Comment: What is the goal? Iterate until you find a match for `key`?

Comment: There are trees, where the node content is split between `key` and `value`.  See `std::map` and *binary search trees*.  The separation speeds up the finding and comparing of the key.

Comment: There is no "better" without context (your real world question). However key won't help while traversing linked list.

Comment: With the `key` outside of the data, the linked list can access the `key` through the node.  With the `key` inside of the data, there is an extra step to access the key or a comparison function is needed.  The question is:  Is this time difference negligible or significant?

Comment: Ask yourself: What's the difference between a linked list with a key and a binary search tree or red/black tree?

Answer (score 0):

> if we compare the space and time complexity of both cases which one is better?

Neither is better in general. Asymptotic space and time complexities are uneffected.

Typically, data structures are more generally useful when they are generic. If you make a template that allows any type of data, you'll find that you can store a key as part of the data if you need it and thereby have essentially implemented both data structures in one template.